# Getting a matrix from items in two files

Tags: python

I have two files from which I want to obtain a matrix of presence (1) and absence (0) below.
if any item in fileB (or col1, dont know which input is best here) matches an item in cols2-4, a score of "1" is recorded, other wise "0" is recorded

file A:

```
 col1   col2    col3    col4
 esd    dus esd muq
 uum    uum dus esd
 dus    esd uum dus
 muq    muq muq uum
```

file B:

```
esd
uum
dus 
muq
```

my attempt:

```
out_file=open("out.txt", "w")
for itemA in open("fileA", "r") as file1:
    file2=open("fileB", "r")
    for row in file2:
        for col in file2:
            if itemA==file2[row][col]:
                out_file.write(int(1))
            else:
                out_file.write(int(0))
```

expected output:

```
    col1    col2    col3
 esd    0   1   0
 uum    1   0   0
 dus    0   0   1
 muq    1   1   0
```

Help with the python code will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual output with your code?

Comment: use pandas. http://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: @boh: looking at the code, my guess would be syntax error ;)

Answer (score 1):

Does something like this work for you?

```
with open('a.txt') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        cols = line.split()
        key = cols[0]
        print key,
        for col in cols[1:]:
            # Print 1 if they are the same, 0 otherwise
            print int(col == key),

        # Newline
        print
```

With `a.txt`:

```
 esd    dus esd muq
 uum    uum dus esd
 dus    esd uum dus
 muq    muq muq uum
```

Output:

```
esd 0 1 0
uum 1 0 0
dus 0 0 1
muq 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need file B if the first item in each row of file A is the thing that you're looking for.

```
result = []
for line in open('input.txt').readlines():
    tokens = line.split()
    seek = tokens[0]  # We seek occurrences of the first token in the row.
    row = [seek]      # This array stores pieces of output.
    for item in tokens[1:]:
        if item == seek:
            row.append('1')   # Note that these are strings, not integers.
        else:                 # You might like to replace them with other
            row.append('0')   #   values such as 'Y'/'N' or 'T'/'F'.
    result.append(row)
lines = ['  '.join(row) for row in result]  # Making lines of output.
text = '\n'.join(lines)                     # Gluing the lines together.
print(text)                                 # Printing for verification.
with open('output.txt', 'w') as out_file:   # Then writing to file.
    out_file.write(text+'\n')
```

The above code will take this input:

```
esd    dus esd muq
uum    uum dus esd
dus    esd uum dus
muq    muq muq uum
```

and produce this output:

```
esd  0  1  0
uum  1  0  0
dus  0  0  1
muq  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column in B does not necessarily match the first column in A, then you could call the `next` method on any of the files to be in a form of synchronized reading:

```
fileA = 'fileA.tsv'
fileB = 'fileB.tsv'
outfilename = 'outfile.tsv'

with open(fileA) as fa:
    with open(fileB) as fb:
        with open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
            for line in fb:
                corresp_a_line = fa.next()
                fields = corresp_a_line.split()
                outfile.write(fields[0])  # write column 1
                for field in fields[1:]:
                    outfile.write("\t{}".format(int(line.strip() in field)))
                outfile.write("\n")
```